# How can I call a view controller in swift 2 at the code?

Tags: ios, swift2

I searched for similar problems, but none solved my problem. I need to call a new view controller , but when I do it a black screen appears , as I do to associate with the main storyboard screen?

Comment: You should look around for tutorials like this one [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion:

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewIdentifier") as! viewNeedToCall
```

You can init and use `vc` with `navigation`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]A black screen appears when the simulator can't figure what to present. It seems lost in the sense which controller it has to present.

If it is the first screen then make sure that you have set the initial view controller in Main.storyboard. If not, then you have to call(instantiate) that view controller using the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` property of a storyboard.

For e.g.If you want to present a ViewController named as YourViewController then

1. Make an object of YourViewController, say yourVCObject.
   `let yourVCObject = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewController") as? YourViewController`
2. Present your desired ViewController with -

`self.presentViewController(yourVCObj!, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Here connect your class YourViewController in the Identity Inspector in the "Class" and type "YourViewController" in the Storyboard ID and check the "Use Storyboard ID"

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you forgot to connect your VCs to a **NAVIGATION CONTROLLER**.

Without Navigation controller you cannot move to another VC.